# How do I assign a variable to a Tkinter input?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using the following code to create a widget with three inputs.

I am able to modify this code to format the widget how I want, but I then need to copy files based on the input from the fields in the widget. For example, if the user inputs `'A'`, `'1'`, and `'X'` then I need to copy file `A1X` from a network drive to the local drive.

I think I need to assign each input field to a variable and then I can set up a conditional to get the correct file, but I cannot figure out how to set up these variables.

```
from tkinter import *
fields = 'Project #', 'Reel #', 'Batch #'

def fetch(entries):
   for entry in entries:
   field = entry[0]
   text  = entry[1].get()
   print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text)) 

def makeform(root, fields):
   entries = []
   for field in fields:
      row = Frame(root)
      lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
      ent = Entry(row)
      row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
      lab.pack(side=LEFT)
      ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
      entries.append((field, ent))
   return entries

if __name__ == '__main__':
   root = Tk()
   ents = makeform(root, fields)
   root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))   
   b1 = Button(root, text='OK',
      command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
   b1.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
   b2 = Button(root, text='Reset', command=root.quit)
   b2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
   root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should use a dictionary for entries.
2. Your function fetch is on the correct path.

Here is a fixed version(assuming entries is a dictionary):

```
def fetch(entries):
   filename = ''.join(entries[f].get() for f in fields)
   print(filename)
   #whatever you want to do with the result
```

Comment: This won't work. You aren't properly getting the values from the Entry widgets.

Comment: I have never used a dictionary, but I read up on them. I came up with" entries = {'Project': , 'Reel': , 'Batch': }, but i'm not sure what to associate each of these fields to since that will be the output of the widget. I have tried several different things, but it keeps giving me syntax or not defined errors.

Comment: In make_forms, you create it with entries = {} then you can replace entries.append((field, ent)) by entries[field] = ent

Comment: Thank you Bryan and Eric. It works great! I am finding that I need to also have a variable set for each individual field (Project#, Reel# and Batch#). I have tried to do this with the original for loop, but i'm having trouble setting each field to a separate variable. Is there a way to set project # = the first entry, reel# is the 2nd entry and batch# is the 3rd entry?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `StringVar()` and provide a `textvariable` to `Entry()`

```
for field in fields:
    row = Frame(root)
    lab = Label(row, width=15, text=field, anchor='w')
    entry_variable = StringVar(root)
    ent = Entry(row, textvariable=entry_variable)
    row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
    lab.pack(side=LEFT)
    ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
    entries.append((field, entry_variable))
```

Get the data (after fixing indentation):

```
def fetch(entries):
    for entry in entries:
        field = entry[0]
        text  = entry[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))
```

Comment: You don't _need_ a `StringVar`. It's certainly a choice, but more often than not it's just an extra object that you don't really need.